# Why might typing in the Google Sheets formula field occasionally write over text as if Insert keyboard feature was on when it is not?

Tags: google-sheets

Within the last couple of weeks when working on various different sheets on different desktop computers I have noticed that as I type in the formula field, text is overwritten on a random approximately 10% of keypresses, as if the Insert key had been momentarily switched on. Can't work out why. Thanks

Comment: I am having the same exact issue, I just paste my formula in notepad++ and start typing my changes then paste back into the formula bar.